# How to resolve deprecated Tess4j method getInstance()?

Tags: java

I am doing an OCR project. `getInstance()` in tess4j is deprecated. I can't use `Tesseract.Tesseract()` even which gives an error. How can I  solve this?

Code with `Tesseract.getInstance()`

[image: Code with Tesseract.getInstance()]

Code with `Tesseract.Tesseract()`

[![Code with Tesseract.Tesseract()][2]][2]

This is what is displayed when I compiled the program after I inserted 
Tesseract tess = new Tesseract() ;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjoG7.png)

Comment: Please add the actual code instead of images

Comment: I think he used images just to visually show how the IDE reported errors and deprecated methods in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deprecated methods can still be used. The `@Deprecated` annotation just means that the library developer plans to stop supporting this method (or remove it from the library) in a future release.

More precisely, from the [@Deprecated documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html),

> A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists.

You may want to check these out:

- [What does it mean for a method to be deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081610/what-does-it-mean-for-a-method-to-be-deprecated)
- [The constructor Date(...) is deprecated. What does it mean? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999766/the-constructor-date-is-deprecated-what-does-it-mean-java)
- [Is it wrong to use Deprecated methods or classes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941900/is-it-wrong-to-use-deprecated-methods-or-classes-in-java)
- [How and When To Deprecate APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html) (Oracle official documentation)
- [What does the deprecated API warning mean?](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0008.html)

[It is not a good practice, however, to use deprecated methods and classes](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MET02-J.+Do+not+use+deprecated+or+obsolete+classes+or+methods), as they may lead to future bugs and compilation problems in your system if the methods or classes are removed and you update the library versions.

---

However, in your case, `Tesseract()` is a class constructor. You are making the wrong call, as the correct one would be

```
Tesseract instance = new Tesseract();
```

Have a look at the [Tess4j documentation](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-2.0/net/sourceforge/tess4j/Tesseract.html) to learn more about the `Tesseract` class.

Comment: After adding the above mentioned code snippet , I compiled my program. Finally it gave an exception which is " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found. ". I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Paste the entire stack trace here or in a site like pastebin.com so we can analyze the problem. :)
Is the `Tesseract` library correctly configured in your build path?

Comment: I Uploaded a screenshot about the stack trace as you suggested. Please help me to configure the error

Comment: Where did you upload the screenshot?

Comment: I edited my first question and added another screen shot in the above

Answer (score 0):

`Tesseract()` is a constructor, so you need to use `new Tesseract()` to get one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Can you please help me with my project problem? I have uploaded new screen shot on stack trace by editing the above question.